# Regex in Haskell - Understanding multi parameter typeclass signatures

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm having hard time figuring out how to use `Text.Regex` package. What does signature below mean?

```
class RegexOptions regex compOpt execOpt 
  | regex->compOpt execOpt, compOpt->regex execOpt, execOpt->regex compOpt
```

I understand that there are three type parameters to `RegexOptions` and that for each of them, the other two allow compiler to determine its type, but how? What are types or constraints on `regex` `compOpt` and `execOpt`?

Side question. What would be the type of this expression?

```
makeRegexOpts (defaultCompOpt { caseSensitive = False }) defaultExecOpt
```

Comment: If you want to know the type of something then it is best to ask the compiler, not other humans. In GHCi  `:t makeRegexOpts (defaultCompOpt { caseSensitive = False }) defaultExecOpt` results in
`makeRegexOpts (defaultCompOpt { caseSensitive = False }) defaultExecOpt
  :: RegexMaker regex (GenLanguageDef s u m) execOpt source =>
     source -> regex`

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson Type will print only when you have selected instances imported. In my case it is `RegexMaker Regex CompOption ExecOption source => source -> Regex`. I was wondering whether broader type can be expressed.

Comment: If it helps, common opinion I've heard is that the `regex-posix` package and friends are really over-eager on the typeclasses and unnecessarily complicated in their API.

Answer (score 1):

> and that for each of them, the other two allow compiler to determine its type

Not quite. Each of them *can be used to deduce the other two*, that's what this fundep says.

How this works? Well, [magic](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/libraries/ghc-7.8.2/src/FunDeps.html)! No. The compiler will only allow you to declare one single instance with any particular type appearing at one of the arguments. Then, when it needs a `RegexOptions` instance and has already deduced any one of the type arguments, it can just look that instance up to obtain the other parameters.